# To show dir() function as a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I read something about string, dictionaries etc. and want to combine this two feature as my small challenge.

I am trying to show `dir` function like this:

1. `__abs__`
2. `__add__`
3. `__and__` etc. until  the end of the `dir`

This is my code:

```
x = ''.split(', ')
dicts = {x : dir(x) for x in range(100)}
print(dicts)
```

The first line does not work at all, even if I comment this line still see:

```
{0: ['__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', '__bool__', '__ceil__', '__class ...
```

The second line shows above result.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. As is, it's hard to understand what you're trying to do in general (the expected result), as well as what you expect either `x = ''.split(', ')` and `dicts = {x : dir(x) for x in range(100)}` to do and how this relate with your main goal. Please read this carefully https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: "_first line does not work at all_" Without telling us what you expect, anybody can say that the first line works fine. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @sqr and welcome to SO. I think I understand what you are trying to do and I may have a solution.

If you input dir(1) in your python prompt, you will see that dir(1) returns a list.

```
>>> dir(1)
['__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', '__bool__', '__ceil__', '__class__', 
'__delattr__', '__dir__', '__divmod__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__float__', 
'__floor__', '__floordiv__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', 
'__getnewargs__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__index__', '__init__', 
'__init_subclass__', '__int__', '__invert__', '__le__', '__lshift__',...]
```

To make it into a dictionary, you have to loop through the list one item at a time.

Try the following code:

```
dicts = {}
i = 1
for item in dir(1):
    dicts[i] = item
    i += 1
```

This will give you a dictionary. Hope this helps.

Comment: More simply: `result = {i:item for i, item in enumate (dir(...), 1)}` - most of the time, when you find yourself maintaining a loop index then you're doing it wrong ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`vars()` is a builtin that does exactly that already, no extra code needed. For certain other applications, you might want to try `locals()` and `globals()` as well.

Comment: Well, the OP will probably be happy to learn about `vars()`, but as he explicitely mentionned, he is using this "problem" to learn how to use dicts and lists etc ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Aneesh Palsule, and bruno desthuilliers you gave me a nice hints :)

I have leveraged them and modified my code. Now this one works as I expected:

```
for index, item in enumerate(dir(1), 1): 
    print (index, item)

Output:
1 __abs__
2 __add__
3 __and__
4 __bool__
5 __ceil__
6 __class__
7 __delattr__
```

But I can not do it by using the list comprehension.

```
result = {i:item for i, item in enumerate (dir(1), 1)}

Output:
{1: '__abs__', 2: '__add__', 3: '__and__', 4: '__bool__', ,...
```

Do you have any idea how to make it with list_comp?

Comment: Please do not use answers to post comments and/or new questions - SO is not a discussion forum, it's a  QA-based technical knowledge base. If you have other questions, post them as new questions.

Comment: Also: `{i:item for i, item in enumerate (dir(1), 1)}` is not a list expression, it's a dict expression.